# Can a Key String in properties file become a variable in another Key String (GWT)?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

in Gwt, we can set message constants at properties file like this

```
passWordErr={0} must contain Upper case
passWordBox=Please enter {0} Here. {0} must contain Upper case
```

in the interface MyMessages, we have:

```
public interface MyMessages extends Messages{
    String passWordErr (String field);
    String passWordBox (String field);
}
```

As you can see, in the properties file we got the duplicated text "`{0} must contain Upper case`". So if we change it, we need to change in 2 places & that is not good.

So my question is:

Can a Key String in  properties file become a variable in another Key String (GWT)?

Something like this:

```
passWordErr={0} must contain Upper case
passWordBox=Please enter {0} Here. + passWordErr({0})
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do that. More importantly, there is no need to do that.

In your example, instead of

```
passWordErr={0} must contain upper case
passWordBox=Please enter {0} here. {0} must contain Upper case
```

it should be

```
passWordErr={0} must contain upper case.
passWordBox=Please enter {0} here.
```

Then, when you need to show a message, you can simply concatenate both messages:

```
Window.alert(myMessages.passWordBox("password") + " " + myMessages.passWordErr("password"));
```

Comment: Hi thax, i found an other solution. passWordBox=Please enter {0} here. {1}. myMessages.passWordBox("password",myMessages.passWordErr("password"));